# Syntax error or access violation: 1059 Identifier name ' ' is too long lumen

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

Estoy haciendo las migraciones a la base de datos con lumen, y me salta el error de que la clave primaria es demasiada larga. Lo que quiero es poner las tres columnas como claves compuestas.

```
    public function up()
{
   if(!Schema::hasTable('asignaturas_alumno')){
        Schema::create('asignaturas_alumno',function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->bigInteger('id_curso_asignatura');
            $table->bigInteger('id_alumno');
            $table->bigInteger('id_curso_escolar');
            $table->primary(['id_alumno','id_curso_escolar','id_curso_asignatura']);
        });
   }

}
```

Este el error:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1059 Identifier name
'asignaturas_alumno_id_alumno_id_curso_escolar_id_curso_asignatura_primary' is 
too long (SQL: alter tabl
e `asignaturas_alumno` add primary key `asignaturas_alumno_id_alumno_id_curso_escolar_id_curso_asignatura_primary`(`id_alumno`, `id_curso_escolar`, `id_curso_asignatura`))



[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1059 Identifier name        'asignaturas_alumno_id_alumno_id_curso_escolar_id_curso_asignatura_primary' is   too long



 [PDOException]
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1059 Identifier name 'asignaturas_alumno_id_alumno_id_curso_escolar_id_curso_asignatura_primary' is   too long
```

Answer (score 5):

Los nombres de columna, de índices, de tablas... y otros están limitados a 64 caracteres en MySQL.

Tienes en alguna parte un identificador (al parecer un nombre de clave primaria) llamado `asignaturas_alumno_id_alumno_id_curso_escolar_id_curso_asignatura_primary` que tiene 73 caracteres y por lo tanto viola esa regla de MySQL.

De ahí el error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1059 Identifier
>   name
>   'asignaturas_alumno_id_alumno_id_curso_escolar_id_curso_asignatura_primary'
>   is  too long (SQL: alter tabl e `asignaturas_alumno` add primary key
>   `asignaturas_alumno_id_alumno_id_curso_escolar_id_curso_asignatura_primary`(`id_alumno`,
>   `id_curso_escolar`, `id_curso_asignatura`))

Generalmente los nombres de claves primarias son cortos, algo como `pk_nombretabla` ;

Ver: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html

### Solución

Asignar un nombre más corto a la primary key en cuestión.

Answer (score 3):

Tal como dice @A.Cedano, tu problema es que la llave primaria tiene un nombre demasiado largo.

A todas luces, cuando declaras

```
$table->primary(['id_alumno','id_curso_escolar','id_curso_asignatura']);
```

Por debajo Laravel o Lumen deduce el nombre de la llave usando la concatenación de los nombres de cada campo, separados con un `_` y añadiéndole el sufijo "_primary".

La solución sería ponerle tú mismo un nombre a tu llave primaria en vez de dejar que el framework eligiera ese nombre por ti.

No uso Laravel pero como me fijé que  `$table` es una instancia de la clase `Blueprint`, y que la clase [Blueprint](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php) está en el repo [laravel/framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework), así que por curiosidad busqué el método `Blueprint::primary` de la clase, y encontré que éste [acepta como segundo parámetro el nombre de la llave](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L354).

```
/**
 * Specify the primary key(s) for the table.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $columns
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  string|null  $algorithm
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
 */
public function primary($columns, $name = null, $algorithm = null)
{
    return $this->indexCommand('primary', $columns, $name, $algorithm);
}
```

Este método llama a su vez al método `indexCommand`:

```
/**
 * Add a new index command to the blueprint.
 *
 * @param  string        $type
 * @param  string|array  $columns
 * @param  string        $index
 * @param  string|null   $algorithm
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
 */
protected function indexCommand($type, $columns, $index, $algorithm = null)
{
    $columns = (array) $columns;
    // If no name was specified for this index, we will create one using a basic
    // convention of the table name, followed by the columns, followed by an
    // index type, such as primary or index, which makes the index unique.
    $index = $index ?: $this->createIndexName($type, $columns);
    return $this->addCommand(
        $type, compact('index', 'columns', 'algorithm')
    );
}
```

El cual dice explícitamente que:

> If no name was specified for this index, we will create one using a
>   basic convention of the table name, followed by the columns, followed
>   by an index type, such as primary or index, which makes the index
>   unique.

**EN RESUMEN**

Debes crear tu índice único como:

```
$table->primary(['id_alumno','id_curso_escolar','id_curso_asignatura'],'asignaturas_alumno_pk');
```

Donde `asignaturas_alumno_pk` es un nombre que yo puse y puedes cambiarlo a lo que gustes.